# How do I refer a file in php which is ahead of two folders

Tags: php

I have the following structure

```
  folder1
    file1.php
    file2.php
 folder2
    folder2.1(folder)
       file2.1.1(file)
```

In the above structure how do I refer to file (file1.php) which in folder1 from file2.1.1.php  which is in folder2.1

Comment: what are you looking to achieve?

Comment: iam looking to access the file1.php from file2.1.1(php) file

Comment: there is no function called "access" in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

`..` takes you up one folder, so (assuming folder2.1 is a child of folder2) you want:

```
../../folder1/file1.php
```

This takes you up two folders (to the parent of folder1 and folder2) and then back down into folder1 to find file1.php

*(Not sure the slashes are the right ones, but you get the picture)*

Comment: THANKS A LOT  THANKS A LO THANKS A LO IT HELPED ME TO SOLVE

Comment: @Ads - if you get an answer that solves your problem then you can (and should) accept it by clicking on the hollow tick underneath the vote score and voting arrows. There is a delay before you can accept so there's no rush, but it shows others that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

well, speaking in terms of files

```
$file = "../../folder1/file1.php"; // worst
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder1/file1.php"; // better
```

Answer (score 0):

If folder 2.1 is within folder 2: `../../folder1/file1.php`

If folder 2.1 is on the same level as folder 1 and folder 2: `../folder1/file1.php`

Comment: I was just giving the path from file A to file B...didn't know if he wanted to include, write to, read from, etc.

Comment: he is talking of files, not HTTP resources. supposedly

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could just use "include" and give it the relative path

```
 include("../../folder1/file1.php");
```

or if you know the absolute path and to give it more versatility:

```
 include("/pathToFolder1/file1.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to prepend

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

to the relative pathname, in order to be sure that the relative path will be expanded correctly in every case.

For example:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../folder1/file1.php';
```